# how to retrieve an attribute by specifying another in python using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

This is snippet of code from an eCommerce website. I need to retrieve the data sort rank of all

---

HTML Code of website

```
< a class="search" data-sort-rank="1" href="/shop/products/Cisco-8841-VoIP-Phone/3371367.aspx?pfm=srh">Cisco 8841 VoIP Phone  
</a>



a class="search-result-product-url" data-sort-rank="2" href="/shop/products/Cisco-8851-VoIP-Phone/3371366.aspx?pfm=srh">Cisco 8851 VoIP Phone 

...

...

... and so on
```

Here is my code. I am using Selenium. I specified the class name and partial text in href as follows to find correct elements. now I want to get data sort ranks of all these elements

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\All\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.mywebsite.com/')

element= driver.find_element_by_class_name (class_name= 'search') and driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Cisco')

element_attribute_value= element.get_attribute('data-sort-rank')

print('rank is' %element_attribute_value)
```

Can anyone please correct my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have the statement:

element= driver.find_element_by_class_name (class_name= 'search') and driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Cisco')

Presumably you have that because you expect that there will be one set of elements with the class name 'search' and one set whose partial text content will be 'Cisco'. A set implies the possibility of more that one element, which in turn implies that you need one of the `find_elements` methods.

Since you're dealing with list results and you need their intersections you need to turn the lists into sets first.

And one minor point, `webdriver.Chrome` takes no argument.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('file://c:/scratch/temp.htm')
>>> search_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search')
>>> cisco_elements = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Cisco')
>>> elements = set(search_elements).intersection(set(cisco_elements))
>>> list(elements)[0].text
'Cisco 8841 VoIP Phone'
>>> element = list(elements)[0]
>>> element.tag_name
'a'
>>> element.get_attribute('data-sort-rank')
'1'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help but it is still giving me the following error --------------Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aga/first.py", line 30, in <module>
    element=list(elements)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I am trying to search a keyword(for ex. phone here) in browser of an eCommerce website and then find  my companies product search result position in the search results.(ex. CISCO here) the website's html has data sort rank. I need to retrieve that to get position

Comment: You should submit that as a separate question. If what I provided above solved the problem you were facing at the time then you should mark it accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, it is the same thing I am doing. This is the question statement and that was the code.

Comment: That error you mentioned at the beginning of this conversation means that whatever you were searching for could not be found and as a result `elements` was `None`. Then result of the expression `list(elements)` would be an empty list which would not have an element `0`. I'm responding in this way because, although I've re-read this conversation several times I still don't understand it.

Comment: Hey I got my mistake but and I think the reason is it finding cisco_elements and search_elements properly but unable to understand that some of cisco elements are search elements also .

Comment: This is how search_elements are displayed.... There are 25 element in it >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2db46079bc650cbcf4ae72caf1d82896", element="0.8711267484071481-1")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2db46079bc650cbcf4ae72caf1d82896", element="0.8711267484071481-2")>, ------------------------------<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2db46079bc650cbcf4ae72caf1d82896", element="0.8711267484071481-25")>]

Comment: And there are three 3 elements in cisco_elements >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2db46079bc650cbcf4ae72caf1d82896", element="0.8711267484071481-26")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2db46079bc650cbcf4ae72caf1d82896", element="0.8711267484071481-27")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2db46079bc650cbcf4ae72caf1d82896", element="0.8711267484071481-28")>]
And that;s why set is empty

Comment: I hope you're not still using the line of code with the `and` in it? That's not going to work.

Comment: Nope I am using the one which you provided

Comment: I'm tapped out. I think I need to know the url you're trying to scrape.

Comment: I posted the question with url and all the details:   Can you please search this in searchbox of stackoverflow. Appreiate your help >>>>>>>>> finding Search result Position using selenium and python